# Apache rewrite/redirect issue

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have the below in my 000-default.conf file (Ubuntu and Apache 2.4.34) yet when I access either www.mydomain.us or mydomain.us I do not get redirected to the https page that does indeed work directly with https://www.mydomain.us

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.mydomain.us
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've there is nothing in the error logs and the access logs shows, as presented however not expected, it's serving the page in /var/www/html.  I've googled but not found anything helpful that matches this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.mydomain.us
> ```

This condition will never match, so the redirect never occurs. The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* makes it into a lexicographical string comparison, so it is attempting to match the `SERVER_NAME` variable (the requested *hostname* by default) against the literal string `*.mydomain.us`.

You would need something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.example\.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable always contains the value of the `Host:` header from the request. By default, `SERVER_NAME` also contains the same value, however,  depending on the value of the `UseCanonicalName` directive, this variable can contain the value used in the `ServerName` directive, not the value from the request.

---

However, you don't necessarily need mod_rewrite for this, a simple mod_alias `Redirect` maybe sufficient:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
```

If you have multiple hosts then configure a separate vHost for each.

Comment: It was matching www.mydomain.us but it still didn't' redirect.  It was setup by a script that probably worked for an older Apache version.  Now will either of your suggestions work only for subdomains not already defined?  Say I have a foo.mydomain.us and a bar.mydomain.us, will they still work?

Comment: "only for subdomains not already defined?" - Use the mod_rewrite (first) suggestion, but remove the `RewriteCond` directive entirely. It will then unconditionally redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on the same home (providing it is caught by the VirtualHost).

Comment: Your Rewrite worked as I expected it.  I was have a *derf* moment.  thanks for the help.